# Is it better to use 10 different sets of tables, or 1 set?

Tags: mysql, database-design, multi-tenant

I have many webshops, all running on the same PHP/mysql backend I made back in the day.

Each webshop has their own set of tables, like 10 each or something, containing data about products, customers, and so on. and a couple 1000 products each.

Example tables

```
mystore_product_info
mystore_category_info
..
mystore2_product_info
mystore2_category_info
```

I just wonder if it could be beneficial for speed to merge them into 1 set of tables, adding 1 column extra to the tables, for identifying which webshop the data is for?

Would end up like this then

```
product_info
category_info
```

or would it rather be slower, with these bigger tables?

Comment: These tables are small enough that you're not going to notice a speed difference either way, if your database & schema are set up remotely sanely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is already separate, I think you're better off keeping it that way.  If these web shops don't have a need to share data then you won't risk cross contaminating them by forgetting to include the extra column on one of your queries.  You're not going to gain any performance benefit by combining them.